# How to join two result into one in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have one result set like below.

```
university_id   name    short_name  region_id   region
1               UTC     UTC         8           Mandalay
2               UM      MC          8           Mandalay
3               SG      SG          12          Sagaing
4               MYIC    MTU         8           Mandalay
5               WWE     EWW         15          Yangon
```

Query for it is

```
SELECT u.*, r.name as region
from universities u
join regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id
where u.region_id = r.region_id;
```

Another one is

```
university_id   count(student_id)
1               12
2               12
3               11
4               11
5               11
```

Query for it

```
select university_id, count(student_id) 
from enrollments
group by university_id;
```

I want to join those 2 results according to `university_id` like below.

```
university_id   name    short_name  region_id   region     count
1               UTC     UTC         8           Mandalay   12
2               UM      MC          8           Mandalay   12
3               SG      SG          12          Sagaing    11
4               MYIC    MTU         8           Mandalay   11
5               WWE     EWW         15          Yangon     11
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT u.*, r.name as region
from universities u
join regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id
where u.region_id = r.region_id
UNION ALL
select university_id, count(student_id) 
from enrollments
group by university_id;
```

Comment: if performance is not a concern then you can very well do a second join with enrollments on university_id
SELECT u.*, r.name as region, count(en.student_id)
from universities u
join regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id
join enrollments en on en.university_id = u.university_id
where u.region_id = r.region_id
group by en.university_id;

Comment: Is it possible for a university to be in more than one region (has more than one campus in different regions)?

Comment: NO. A university exists in only one region.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UNION ALL,
Use This.

```
INNER JOIN TABLE_NAME ON universities u.university_id=enrollments.university_id;
```

Comment: You can get it from   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
SELECT 
    u.*, 
    r.name as region, 
    count(student_id) 
from universities u 
join regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id 
join enrollments e ON e.university_id = u.university_id
where u.region_id = r.region_id group by university_id;
```